# How to change Parent Activity layout from Child Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity that displays  Google Map on the full Screen.

I have a child activity that extends `MapsActivity`.

When i extend child from Parent it displays `Map` on the whole screen.

In `Child Activity`, i need to add Map at the top and a  list view at the bottom, that will be implemented in `Child Activity Layout`.

I tried to do this but it gave me following error message,

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child
>   already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent
>   first.

```
public class PlacesListActivity extends GoogleMapsActivity{

    View parentFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);

        parentFragment= findViewById(R.id.g_map);

        LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        linearLayout.addView(parentFragment);
```

In the above code, I am not using `ChildActivity` Layout, but if i use it, it did not get the elements of Parent Activity.

Comment: As the error says, parentFragment which is I will assume is your map is already set on a parent. You may have to create a new map and add it to your linear layout. This is all an assumption. You might have to post your xml file so we could see it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the view of the parent by using following aproach:

```
View viewToBeRemoved= view.findViewById(R.id.view_to_be_removed);
View parent = viewToBeRemoved.getParent();
if (parent != null) {
    ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(viewToBeRemoved);
}
parent.addView(modifiedViewToBeAdded);
```

> But it is not recommended approach.

Recommended approach is to use Maps fragment in the half of your activity and show the list in remaining portion of activity.

Please see this thread for [How to use MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)